# Empty Cell in HTML Table when filled with PHP Array

Tags: php, html, html-table

I just filled a html table with an php array, but now I see that I have some empty cells. The code which builds the table is:

```
echo "<table id='data' style='border: 1px solid black'><tbody>";
echo "<th>Country </th>";
echo "<th>Counter</th>";
foreach($analysis_data as $row){
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach(['country','counter'] as $attribute){
        echo "<td>".$row[$attribute]."<td>";
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</tbody></table>';
```

There is a screenshot what the table currently looks like

[image]

If I use `var_dump($analysis data)` it looks like

```
array(9) { [0]=> array(2) { ["country"]=> string(30) "Germany " ["counter"]=> int(34) } [1]=> array(2) { ["country"]=> string(30) "Vorarlberg " ["counter"]=> int(2) } [2]=> array(2) { ["country"]=> string(30) "Oberoesterreich " ["counter"]=> int(9) } [3]=> array(2) { ["country"]=> string(30) "Wien " ["counter"]=> int(5) } [4]=> array(2) { ["country"]=> string(30) "Switzerland " ["counter"]=> int(3) } [5]=> array(2) { ["country"]=> string(30) "Salzburg " ["counter"]=> int(6) } [6]=> array(2) { ["country"]=> string(30) "Niederoesterreich " ["counter"]=> int(1) } [7]=> array(2) { ["country"]=> string(30) "Czech Republic " ["counter"]=> int(3) } [8]=> array(2) { ["country"]=> string(30) "Steiermark " ["counter"]=> int(1) } }
```

Does anybody where this empty cells come from and how to delete them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix your html markup:

```
// Create `thead` for header and open `tr` for first row
echo "<table id='data' style='border: 1px solid black'><thead><tr>";
echo "<th>Country </th>";
echo "<th>Counter</th>";

// Close `tr` and `thead`, open `tbody`
echo "</tr></thead><tbody>";

foreach($analysis_data as $row){
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach(['country','counter'] as $attribute){
        echo "<td>".$row[$attribute]."</td>";    // close `td` here
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</tbody></table>';
```

Comment: `echo "<td>".$row[$attribute]."<td>";` be careful with the closing for tags, it'll spawn unnecessary cells